# kotlin async calls are called in sequence unless called with GobalScope

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

okay, so I have a controller method which need to make a bunch of soap call to an external service, each one quite heavy. I am trying to do these one in parralel to save some time, but unless I build the `async` calls from GlobalScope, the deferred are resolved in sequence. Let me show you.

executing the following code

```kotlin
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(path = ["/buildSoapCall"])
fun searchStations(): String = runBlocking {

    var travels: List<Travel> = service.getTravels().take(500)
    val deferred = travels
            .map {
                async() {
                    print("START")
                    val result = service.executeSoapCall(it)
                    print("END")
                    result
                }
            }
    println("Finished deferred")
    val callResults = deferred.awaitAll()
    println("Finished Awaiting")

    ""
}
```

get me the following console message :

```
Finished deferred
START-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-END.....
```

the `-` is printed by `executeSoapCall`

As you can see, the deferred are called in sequence.

But if I use `GlobalScope`, like this :

```kotlin
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(path = ["/buildSoapCall"])
fun searchStations(): String = runBlocking {

    var travels: List<Travel> = service.getTravels().take(500)
    val deferred = travels
            .map {
                GlobalScope.async() {
                    print("START")
                    val result = service.executeSoapCall(it)
                    print("END")
                    result
                }
            }
    println("Finished deferred")
    val callResults = deferred.awaitAll()
    println("Finished Awaiting")

    ""
}
```

I get the following console message :

```
Finished Treating 
STARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTSTARTFinished deferred
START-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART--ENDENDSTARTSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-ENDSTART-END...START-END-END-END-END-END-END-END-END-END-END-END-ENDFinished Awaiting
```

showing that the Deferred are all starting in parallel. In addition, the treatment time is quite shorter.

I don't really understand why I have this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `service.executeSoapCall` blocks the thread `runBlocking` coroutine is running on. You need to start `async` coroutine on a different thread everytime to get a concurrent behavior. You can achieve that by using a threadpool, e.g., `Dispatchers.IO`:

```
...
async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    print("START")
    val result = service.executeSoapCall(it)
    print("END")
    result
}
...
```

or creating a new thread on every call:

```
...
async(newSingleThreadContext("MyThread")) {
    print("START")
    val result = service.executeSoapCall(it)
    print("END")
    result
}
...
```

`GlobalScope` works because it uses a ThreadPool by default but you should avoid using it. You can read [this article](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc) by [Roman Elizarov](https://medium.com/@elizarov) about that topic.

Comment: The second example results in a leak, those threads don't die when their coroutine completes.

Comment: What's bother me is that if I replace the call to service.executeSoapCall(it) by delay(500), I got the expected behavior. First I thought that was because delay is a suspend function but no.

Comment: @Teocali Actually you were right, that's the reason. While `service.executeSoapCall(it)` is a blocking call, `delay(500)` is not. If you called `Thread.sleep(500)` instead of `delay(500)` you would get a sequential behavior again. If `executeSoapCall` method was suspendable then you would get a concurrent behavior as long as you use another thread to execute its code. You can achieve that with a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block.